# Error trying to find all the prime numbers from 2 to n using Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++

Tags: c++

I need to find all the prime numbers from 2 to n using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I looked on Wikipedia([Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) to find out what the Sieve of Eratosthenes was, and it gave me this pseudocode:

```
Input: an integer n > 1

Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
initially all set to true.

for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
  if A[i] is true:
    for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n :
      A[j] := false

Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

So I used this and translated it to C++. It looks fine to me, but I have a couple errors. Firstly, if I input 2 or 3 into n, it says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Range_error'
what(): Range_error: 2
```

Also, whenever I enter a 100 or anything else (4, 234, 149, 22, anything), it accepts the input for n, and doesn't do anything. Here is my C++ translation:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
/* this program will take in an input 'n' as the maximum value. Then it will calculate
all the prime numbers between 2 and n. It follows the Sieve of Eratosthenes with
the algorithms from Wikipedia's pseudocode translated by me into C++*/

int n;
cin >> n;
vector<string>A;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) // fills the whole table with "true" from 0 to n-2
    A.push_back("true");

for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); ++i)
{
    i -= 2; // because I built the vector from 0 to n-2, i need to reflect that here.
    if(A[i] == "true")
    {
        for(int j = pow(i, 2); j <= n; j += i)
        {
            A[j] = "false";
        }
    }
}

//print the prime numbers
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if(A[i] == "true")
        cout << i << '\n';
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you want to do with that i -= 2 ?

Comment: You need to adjust `i` in that last loop, too.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Why did you use a vector of string instead of a vector of bool (or worst case scenario int) ? It's way more easy to compare two bools or ints than two strings.

Comment: @Martze C++ vectors are indexed from 0 to n right? But I start with 2. So I moved 'i' down 2 so that it would correspond with the 0 index

Comment: @Loufylouf when I used a vector with a bool it through up an error on the if(A[i] = true) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from the fact that the indexes are not in line with the value they are representing, i.e., they are moved down by 2. By doing this operation, they no longer have the same mathematical properties.

Basically, the value 3 is at position 1 and the value 4 is at position 2. When you are testing for division, you are using the positions as they were values. So instead of testing if 4%3==0, you are testing that 2%1=0.

In order to make your program works, you have to remove the `-2` shifting of the indexes:

```
int main()
{

int n;
cin >> n;
vector<string>A;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) // fills the whole table with "true" from 0 to n-2
    A.push_back("true");

for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); ++i)
{
    if(A[i] == "true")
    {
        for(int j = pow(i, 2); j <= n; j += i)
        {
            A[j] = "false";
        }
    }
}

//print the prime numbers
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if(A[i] == "true")
        cout << i << '\n';
}


return 0;
}
```

I agree with other comments, you could use a vector of bools. And directly initialize them with the right size and value:

```
std::vector<bool> A(n, false);
```

Comment: When I use a bool, this comes up: T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
 {
  if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
  return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
 }  // with an error at the return statement. This is in the header file std_lib_facilities.h

Answer (score 0):

Here you push back `n-1` elements

```
vector<string>A;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) // fills the whole table with "true" from 0 to n-2
    A.push_back("true");
```

but here you access your vector from `A[2]` to `A[n]`.

```
//print the prime numbers
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if(A[i] == "true")
        cout << i << '\n';
}
```

`A` has elements at positions `A[0]` to `A[n-2]`. You might correct this defect by initializing your vector differently. For example as

```
vector<string> A(n+1, "true");
```

This creates a vector `A` with `n+1` strings with default values "true" which can be accessed through `A[0]` to `A[n]`. With this your code should run, even if it has more deficits. But I think you learn most if you just try to successfully implement the sieve and then look for (good) alternatives in the internet.

Answer (score -3):

This is painful. Why are you using a string array to store boolean values, and not, let's say, an array of boolean values? Why are you leaving out the first two array elements, forcing you to do some adjustment of all indices? Which you then forget half the time, totally breaking your code? At least you should change this line:

```
i -= 2; // because I built the vector from 0 to n-2, i need to reflect that here.
```

to:

```
i -= 2; // because I left the first two elements out, I that here.
// But only here, doing it everywhere is too annoying.
```

As a result of that design decision, when you execute this line:

```
    for(int j = pow(i, 2); j <= n; j += i)
```

i is actually *zero* which means j will stay zero forever.

Comment: Dude, whenever I use bool to represent the vector, I have an error in my std_lib_facilities.h